# Does PHP always support passing more arguments than the method expected?

Tags: php

I have tried on PhpFiddle and the PHP version on PhpFiddle supports passing more arguments than the method expected without giving any error, but not vice versa.

In my project some of my clients' server PHP version is quite old, so I would to assure that is this behavior always supported in all versions of PHP?

Comment: No, and most internal/built-in functions object if too many arguments are passed in ([See](https://3v4l.org/nSRlM)); it's only user-defined functions that silently discard spurious arguments

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Passing more arguments to your classes' methods than what's defined in the method's signature is already supported in PHP 4. If you want to use the ... token, that's only supported since PHP 5.6 http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: The link you have provided only mentions about the support of ... in PHP5.6. Is there any documentation that mentions about the support of passing more args than expected in PHP4?

Comment: Well, I believe the function func_get_args exists exactly for that, to allow calling a function with more arguments than were defined in the signature http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

That function is available since PHP 4.


The PHP 4 documentation is still available for download:
http://doc.php.net/archives/php4/


Even there in the examples for func_num_args() you'll find an example that passes more arguments than defined in the function. If you download the chunked xhtml archive, you'll find it in php-chunked-xhtml/function.func-get-args.html

Answer (score 8):

When passing too many arguments to a **user defined function**, PHP doesn't crash.

This has previously been reported as a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=13892), but with the current status: WONTFIX (a problem that won't be fixed).

Comment: There are perfectly valid use cases for passing many arguments to a UDF without specifying them in the function definition, such as wehn using `function_get_args()`, so this certainly isn't a bug

Comment: @MarkBaker Absolutely, but you can't feel safe using it if you're not sure that it's not considered a bug and that the behavior will never be changed in future versions of PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker the function is called **func_get_args()**. Just for everyone wondering why their code does not work